# how to fill text on the point in my chart use jQuery.flot.js?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, flot

i use [flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) to draw my chart, i want draw a circle with some text on that in my data, i use symbol property in point, my code like this:

```
 points: {
                    show: true,
                    symbol: self.drawSymbol,
                    fillColor: 'blue'
                },
 drawSymbol: function(ctx, x, y, radius, shadow) {
        ctx.arc(x, y, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fill('65kg',x,y);
    },
```

this is not all code, the drawSymbol method invoked in every time drawing my data, my the chart didn't show as my expect,

[image]

you see, the text was covered by the circle, how could this happen?

how to draw a text on my point?

is there any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within flots point drawing routine, it calls the custom symbol function (which in your case writes the text) and then after that (on top) it fills the symbol with your blue color.  To do what you want you'll have to disable flots fill and fill it yourself inside your `drawSymbol` *before you write the text*.

In your options:

```
points: {
    show: true,
    symbol: drawSymbol,
    fill: false // disable flots fill
},
```

And modify your drawSymbol to:

```
var drawSymbol = function(ctx, x, y, radius, shadow) {
   ctx.arc(x, y, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
   ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
   ctx.fill(); // fill it yourself
   ctx.font = "12px 'Segoe UI'";
   ctx.fillStyle = "white";
   ctx.textAlign = 'center';
   ctx.fillText('65kg', x, y + 4); //now the text
}
```

Here's a fiddle [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSamZ/).

[image]

To access your data from `drawSymbol`:

```
var drawSymbol = function(ctx, x, y, radius, shadow) {
    // keep track of how many times you've called this
    if (this.numCalls == undefined){
       this.numCalls = -1;
    }
    this.numCalls++;
    // flot "over" draws
    // so always keep the index correct...
    if (this.numCalls >= someData[0].data.length){
        this.numCalls = this.numCalls - someData[0].data.length;
   }
   //console.log(this.numCalls);
   ctx.arc(x, y, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
   ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.font = "12px 'Segoe UI'";
   ctx.fillStyle = "white";
   ctx.textAlign = 'center';
   // access your data point
   ctx.fillText(someData[0].data[this.numCalls][3]+'kg', x, y + 4);
}
```

Updated [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSamZ/2/).

Comment: What if i want pass my data to drawSymbol method? I want the text on point is same as my data i pass to yaxis,but i check that the drawSymbol doesn't has my data parameter, what should i do?

Comment: @JackZhang, that's a tough one.  I'd store the data globally and then access based on how my times you've called the drawSymbol routine, see updated answer above.